# Project folder structure with CakePHP inclusion

Tags: php, cakephp

I am making a Project which has following folder structure:

- contents
- css
- js
- img
- fonts
- php

Currently I am using core PHP files to furnish my sign-up, log-in, feedback tasks. I am planning to replace my core PHP files with some framework, such as CakePHP. But, I want to put CakePHP or another PHP framework's files in the `php` directory only, as it is.

I want to know if this is possible with CakePHP, or any other framework that I may use for PHP backend?

> Note: I cannot change my folder structure for Cake or any other
>   framework!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the **CakePHP** Folder structure, but you should have clean **MVC** structure. Without changing a single folder in your structure, this is not possible.

If you really can't change the folder structure, as you should, you can't just take a framework as it is. There are several ways to "build" a framework based on existing packages, such as Zend Framework or Symfony, but they all require a lot of reading.

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer

Or something like this:

http://fabien.potencier.org/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1.html